# Rounding nvd3 angularJS percentages for cummulative line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

Hi I am using a line chart exactly like this:

http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/cumulative.line.chart.html

but I was wonder if there was a way to edit the y axis max and min values (and the values in the tooltip) so they don't display these super long decimals.

I went into the nvd3 file and found them there and manage to round them using Math.round...but I was wondering if there was a way to fix this so I don't have to modify the actual nvd3 file.

Answer (score 0):

For the yAxis range try  `chart.forceY([MinValue, MaxValue])`

And to override your tooltip try :

```
.tooltip(function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
    // You can use Math.round on y or x decimal place 
    return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' + '<p>' + y + ' at ' + x + '</p>'
});
```

Hope it helps.